# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2014 Express, tried everything

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssms-2014

I just installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio for the 3rd time and I just can't figure out how to log in.

[image: This is the error I get]

This is the error I get. I read all the threads about it. The server is running, TCP is enabled, the port is 1433, I put sql on the firewall exceptions. I'm lost

I really don't know what else to do. I tried the 2008 version too and same problem.

This is what I installed [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: But I do have the Database Engine or so I think.  I updated the post to show what I have installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to `Start Menu > Microsoft SQL Server > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager`, you should see something like this:

[image]

If there is an entry for `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`, then you're fine - then you have the SQL Server Express database engine installed, up and running. You can connect to it using `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name.

If you **don't see** any entries for "SQL Server" - then you **don't have** SQL Server (the database engine) installed.

**Update:** OK, so you have an instance up and running, but it's `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` which means it's the **default, unnamed instance** - you can connect to it using `.` or `(local)` .

Comment: I edited my post and posted a pic of what I have in SQL server service

Comment: @Charlotte45: updated my response - try using `.` or `(local)` to connect to your server

Comment: Oh my gosh :| it worked! Thank you so so much! None of the other answers online mentioned anything about that.